# Rhomobile Rhodes - Camera::take_picture doesn't redirect to callback url

Tags: ruby, rhomobile, rhodes

I'm using Rhodes to develop a simple program to take a photo and send it to remote server.

Here's the camera action:

```
def camera
  @form = Form.find(@params['id'])
  Camera::take_picture(url_for(:action => :show, :id => @params['id']))
end
```

However, when called it does not redirect back to the 'show' action, as described [in the documentation](http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhodes/device-caps#camera).
Instead, it renders the 'camera' view.
I've also tried writing something like this in the camera control:

```
<div data-role="page">
  <img src="<%= @params['image_uri'] %>;">
</div>
```

But the image is empty anyway

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the redirect action after the camera call, such as:

```
def camera
  @form = Form.find(@params['id'])
  Camera::take_picture(url_for(:action => :show, :id => @params['id']))

  redirect :action => :show
end
```